# Number of rows with exactly 1 numerical value in matrice (R)

Tags: r

I have a matrice that is as such:

```
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0
[11,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
[12,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1
[13,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[14,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[15,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[16,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[17,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
      [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17]
 [1,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 [2,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 [3,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 [4,]     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 [5,]     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 [6,]     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 [7,]     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 [8,]     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0
 [9,]     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0
[10,]     1     1     0     0     0     1     0     0
[11,]     1     1     0     1     1     0     0     0
[12,]     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
[13,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[14,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[15,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[16,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[17,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
      [,18]
 [1,]     0
 [2,]     0
 [3,]     0
 [4,]     0
 [5,]     0
 [6,]     0
 [7,]     0
 [8,]     0
 [9,]     0
[10,]     0
[11,]     0
[12,]     0
[13,]     0
[14,]     0
[15,]     0
[16,]     0
[17,]     0
```

How can I count the number of rows with exactly 1 value, not more than one?

I've tried using `nrow(imageMatrix[imageMatrix < 2])`
and also tried converting the matrice to dataframe and then using `nrow(dataframe_matrice[dataframe_matrice == 1,])`

but it has been of no avail.

Here imageMatrix is the name of the matrice.

Can someone please offer me a hint on what I'm doing wrong with my first line of code in counting rows?

Comment: Also whenever I use the code to calculate the number of rows above, the answer is always NULL. I tried to check if it's right by setting the value to 1 or 0 instead of 2 and it still shows NULL. That means I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use `rowSums` on a logical matrix (`imageMatrix == 1)` and then create a logical vector `== 1` and get the count with `sum`

```
sum(rowSums(imageMatrix == 1) == 1)
```

---

`imageMatrix <2` is a logical `matrix`, when it is used to subset the original matrix, it returns a `vector` of values which doesn't have `dim` and thus `nrow` wouldn't work i.e.

```
nrow(1:5)
NULL
```

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry but a bit new to this. Can you please share why you set imageMatrix == 1 in brackets first? I believe (rowSums(imageMatrix == 1) == 1) is used to see that the sum of row is always equal to 1, right?

Just trying to get a grasp of how the code works.

Comment: @DennisMain `imageMatrix == 1` is a logical matrix where it returns TRUE wherever there is 1 valu, then we use `rowSums` to get the count per row which will be a vector.  This count can be 0, 1, 2, .et c.  but you want the count of 1s, i.e. the reason I used `==1` and get the sum again

Comment: Thanks a ton for the explanation! Now I understood it, thank you very much.